# Sending a variable from javascript to php to be checked and back to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, validation

I am using JavaScript to validate my form. It's basic validation. The step I am having problems with it sending the synum variable via post from java script to my php page valid_synum.php where I do a pdo look up to check if that synum exists or not then I echo a 1 or a 0 based on the result. I want the java script to take that result and either send an alert error or if ok allow the form to submit. Here is the javascript I have. As far as I can tell the POST call

> $.post("valid_synum.php", { synum: synum },

is never called up. I placed a test in the php page and the test never gets activated from the script. It works fine if I load the php directly in a browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script> 
function isNumber(input)
{

return (input - 0) == input && (input+'').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "").length > 0;
}

function checkForm(f)
{
     if (f.elements['worknum'].value != "") 
    { 
     if ((isNumber(f.elements['worknum'].value)) == false)
        {
        alert("The Work Order Number is not valid")
        return false;
        }
        var chars = 6;
    if((f.elements['worknum'].value).length != 6)   
        {
        alert("The Work Order Number is not 6 digits")
        return false;
        }
    }

    if (f.elements['synum'].value == "") 
    {
        alert("Please Enter the Store Number");
        return false;
    }
     if (f.elements['worknum'].value == "") 
    {
        alert("Please Enter the Work Order Number");
        return false;
    }

    if (f.elements['synum'].value != "")
        {
        //get the username  
        var synum = (f.elements['synum'].value);  


        $.post("valid_synum.php", { synum: synum },  
            function(result){  

                     //if the result is 1  
                if(result == 1){  
                    //do nothing valid synum 
                    alert("Good") 
                    return false; 
                }else{  
                    //show that the username is NOT available  
                    alert("The store number is NOT valid. Please Enter full store number") 
                    return false; 
                }  
        }); 

    }   

    else
    {
        f.submit();
        return false;
    }

}


</script>
```

Here is my php page code:

```
$id=$_POST['synum'];

try{
$conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server= $eautoserver ; Database = $eautodb ", $eautouser,    $eautopwd);
   $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM vw_DCR_Web_Customer_Query WHERE CustomerNumber= :id');
 $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
$row = $stmt->fetch();

} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if ($row){
echo 1;
$email_body="1";
}else{
echo 0;
$email_body="0";
}
```

Comment: If you put an alert before the .post, does it display the alert? Meaning, does it even get to the post code?

Comment: Yes if I do alert(synum); just before the $.post it does show me what was entered. All the other error checking that the java script does works fine. It's just this one piece that doesn't seem to activate. I placed code on the php to send a email if it is accessed just to test if the page was being accessed and it is not.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: No the page it's self and the program I use for code editing are not showing any error.

Comment: try changing the {synam : synam} to {synam : synamVal} and var synumVal = (f.elements['synum'].value); . might be the problem, might not

Answer (score 1):

I should check if open/close square brackets are OK to know why your code is not entering in the desired condition.

By the way, you can test if a string is a number and validate if it's empty in a cleaner way.

```
function isNumber(number){ 
    return !isNaN(+number) && number !== ""
}
```

Comment: This way you don't need to create a Regex object each time you call the function...

Comment: Thanks I will adjust that.

Comment: with your statement " open/close square brackets " you mean to make sure that my var synum = (f.elements['synum'].value);  actually has the data I am expecting? I have I placed an alert before the post to test the data to confirm it is what was entered in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this blog post will help you: http://blog.secull.org/php-functions-in-javascript/
There is an similar problem and it is shown, how one can solve it.

mate

Answer (score 0):

I changed how I setup the code and removed

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#synum").change(function() {      
$.post("valid_synum.php", { synum: synum },  
        function(result){  

                 //if the result is 1  
            if(result == 1){  
                //do nothing valid synum 
                alert("Good") 
                return false; 
            }else{  
                //show that the username is NOT available  
                alert("The store number is NOT valid. Please Enter full store number") 
                return false; 
            }  
    });
```

from within my checkform function once it was a separate function it started to work on the fly correctly.